# In R, how to sum multiple columns based on value of another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, I have a dataframe, so that I have One Variable (the name of a country), a number of variables (Population, Number of cars, etc) and then a Column that represents region.

I would like to sum the variables (1, 2, ....) based on the value of the last region. I think this should be possible with dplyr and summarise each, but I cannot get it to work.

Would someone be able to help me please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: please give a small sample of your `data.frame` e.g. with `head()`

Comment: Here it is (I struggle to get it to work)

Comment: ok if `d <- data.frame(...)` can you give us something like `dput(head(d))` and edit your question to include the data?

Comment: I am struggling to enter it. If I paste it, the formatting is strange. The columns are country, variable 1, variable 2, variable 3, and region

Comment: Ok, I will do...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Reading the response (althought this may change if you can get some of your dataframe together...

```
library(dplyr)
summarized_df <- df %>%
    group_by(region) %>%
        summarise(var1=sum(variable1), var2=sum(variable2), var3=sum(variable3))
```

If this doesn't seem to work, maybe you can post your code and the errors even if you can't post the dataframe.